# Hyperref with Pdfcomment

Tags: hyperref

I'm using the below code to get hyperlink with bookmarks

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvips,breaklinks,unicode,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopenlevel=3,pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.25}]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
%    pdfpagemode=none,%
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue
}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\def\popuptext{Deleted Text}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{red}{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\pdfcomment[author={\popuptext},subject={Deleted Text},icon=Comment,voffset=-12pt,color={0 0 1}]{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFAQdel}[1]{{\pdfcomment[author={\popuptext},subject={Deleted Text},icon=Comment,voffset=-12pt,color={0 0 1}]{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the book}

\maketitle

See section~\ref{sec1}

See section~\ref{sec2}

See section~\ref{sec3}

See section~\ref{sec4}

\section{First A head}\label{sec1}

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\section{Second A head}\label{sec2}

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\section{Third A head}\label{sec3}

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\section[Dynamic-marking\ prediction]{This is a sample \protect\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Dynamic marking}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{Dynamic-marking}\DIFaddend\ prediction}\label{sec4}

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\end{document}
```

When I click the second bookmark the PDF view goes exactly to the left side of the section number.

[image]

Whereas for the 4th section the link does not goes exactly to the section number.

[image]

Could you please suggest how should I get the view as shown below

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Besides it being at the bottom of the page?